# Use windows command line to copy files that match, with exceptions?

Tags: windows, cmd

I need to copy a number of files stored in a number of directories to a several other directories. I managed to do this fairly easily, but one file name is proving a bit more challenging, because it conflicts with other file names. Here's what I have so far:

```
SET %ITER% = %%G
FOR /R H:\FILES\ "%%G" IN (RC*.pdf) DO (
    IF %ITER:~0,3% == "RCC" ()
    IF %ITER:~0,3% == "RCS" ()
    ELSE ( COPY "%%G" H:\RC\ )
    )
PAUSE
```

I need to copy all files whose name matches RC, but skip any file that matches RCC or RCS, as those go in a separate directory. The files are named "RC 0000.pdf" where 0000 is a number.

Comment: Don't use a shell script (batch file). Use PowerShell instead. The `Copy-Item` cmdlet has the `-exclude` parameter. (You might as well start learning PowerShell now. The investment will be well worth it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
    dir /a-d /b /s "h:\files\RC*.pdf"
    ^| findstr /r /i /e /c:"\\RC[^SC][^\\]*\.pdf"
') do copy "%%a" h:\rc\
```

Use `dir` command to enumerate all the `RC*.pdf` files, and use the `findstr` command to filter this list, removing the non needed files